# Sending netlink_multicast message from softirq context like netfilter hooks

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, multicast, netlink, softirq

I have registered a hook at the `NF_NETDEV_INGRESS`, very early in the network processing path and I am doing some filtering and based on match, I want to send a notification in user space.

Since user space is listening and doesn't send data to kernel, I am planning to use `nlmsg_multicast()`.

However is it safe to call `nlmsg_multicast` from the **softirq** context which the **hook** function will be executing ?

THis will also involve calling `nlmsg_new(NLMSG_ALIGN(msg_size + 1), GFP_ATOMIC);` in the same interrupt context.